# Issues with axios ("random" network error)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

A few days ago my client would get a network error, I didn't really bother to figure out why because I would simply restart my server and re-run my client and it would work. However, since yesterday I've been constantly getting network error and no matter how many times I restart the server/client, it still doesn't work. I even went back to a branch that I knew was 100% working and I get the same issue. 
I haven't changed anything that might've affected this (i.e. didn't change versions/update anything).

```
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.BASE_API, // api base_url
  timeout: 5000 
})
```

```
service.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    console.log('err' + error) // for debug
    Message({
      message: error.message,
      type: 'error',
      duration: 5 * 1000
    })
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)
```

[The errors that I'm getting are from net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu6Yc.png)

One of the solutions that seem to work for others is to add the following when creating an axios instance:

rejectUnauthorized: false

However, that didn't change anything for me.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why your localhost load on https, not http? Did you install the cert for localhost to your chrome because it seems that google chrome refuse to load this https page due to missing the cert

Comment: I didn't set it to be https, I'm new to the project. It's weird that it was working before and now it doesn't. I put the following on chrome "chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost" and it's working now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: great, i put an answer, please help mark it as answer and vote up if it helps you, this will help other people easy find the solutions if they encounter same problem . thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are running localhost on https with no certificate. Google Chrome don't like this and stop user from using it by flagging the error.

You can create a local certificate to make chrome trust your localhost. I found this post make a very details tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/

Otherway like you says, can force the chrome to disable checking on localhost by disable flag `"chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost"`

However, I suggest that we shouldn't use https on localhost when doing development, it should only be on production env. Http should be enough for localhost